# client's not receveing internet with dhcp. does if i use static

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, dhcp, internet

i reloaded my ad, dhcp, dns server 3 day's ago. server 2008 enterprise. and we are having a problem. only the server issue's the ip. all files share's, ad, etc works. can ping and remote desktop protical into server local. go to ping out of network and it pull's ip and say's the network is unreachable. if i manually set the ip on the unit's the net pull's just fine.....pulling my hair out.

Comment: Have you double checked the DHCP configuration, scope, scope and server options to make sure that everything is correct? Have you verified that the clients are getting a valid ip configuration from DHCP?

Comment: Yes. all that is fine.

Comment: i have uploaded a screen shot of server config windows. http://i40.tinypic.com/wbwdiu.png as well as here is ipconfig print out Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::99ac:c5de:b87c:7171%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.30
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks an awful lot like your DHCP config giving out a bad gateway address (or bad routing options, but that's uncommon).

Comment: yes i have varified all of the info via ipconfig in windows of ifconfig in linux all gateway and dns is correct. with bad routing options how would that work out if i manualy set ip it work's just fine?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sharing out DNS servers?  `127.0.0.1` is valid on the server, but not for the clients, your DHCP should be sharing out the public IP of the server (`192.168.0.1`)  With the localhost/loopback address you're telling each client that is itself a DNS server (which it isn't, so they don't know how to translate names into IPs).

I guess when you say "network is unreachable" do you mean you cannot ping an external IP, or just when you try to ping by name it fails?

Comment: i found the problem in dhcp i set router ip to 127.0.0.1. which was causeing the problem. and yes when i went to ping google.com or even use the ip it was giveing the same error or  destination host unreachable. thank's for all the help every one.